# 3 byte signed value to 4byte signed value

Tags: c, int, signed

I have a 3 byte signed value:

0xffe8a4

That I need to store in a 4 byte signed (32bit) INT, as the sign bit is located at bit 24 doing a straight cast to a 32bit INT does not preserve the negative element of the value and so changes it to a positive number.

How do I do the conversion to a 32bit number and preserve the original intended value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you kept these 3 byte signed value? what data type?

Comment: It's built from an unsigned byte array as part of a packet

Comment: The first question that MUST be asked BEFORE any code could be sensibly designed is: how is your 3-byte integer stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test the sign bit, and if it's `0`, prepend you number with `0x00`, otherwise prepend it with `0xff`.
Like so (warning: didn't test it):

```
int yourCustomNumberIsStoredHere = 0xffe8a4; //I know it won't actually be your number, because int is 4 byte, but I don't know how your store it in your program.
int result = yourCustomNumberIsStoredHere;
if (yourCustomNumberIsStoredHere & (0x80 << 16))
    result |= 0xff << (24);
```

A reference on the topic: [Wikipedia: Two's complement (how negative numbers are stored in memory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 2):

If the number is positive:

*0xffe8a4 -> 0x00ffe8a4*

If the number is negative:

*0xffe8a4 -> 0xffffe8a4*

Use **|**, **>>**, **<<** operators

Answer (score 2):

Here, you need to get the absolute value of your number in order to store it in a regular int.

```
int val = 0xffe8a4 ;
val = -(((~val)&0xffffff) + 1); // val is now the negative number stored as a 4 byte int
// val = ~((~val)&0xffffff); also works ;)
```

You could also proceed like this :

```
int val = 0xffe8a4;
val = val|((val&0x80000)*0xff000000);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data are three separately addressed bytes in memory, then

```
int32 result = ((int)(signed char) HiByte << 16)
             + ((unsigned char)MidByte << 8) + (unsigned char) LoByte;
```

First term forces a sign-bit extension (by casting signed-byte to int), the remainig part is just positioning octets in the resulting value. Separate addressing of input bytes assures the result will be correct both in big-endian and in low-endian systems.